# Couldn't migrate connection items from Talend 5.2 (Open source) to Talend Entreprise (8.0)

Tags: talend

We migrated from the free version (5.2.0) to 8.0, so I had to import my projects to that new version. All the items are readable by the new version, except connection items.

Is there anyone who has the same problem? How did you fix it?

Comment: Since you have Talend Entreprise, your best bet is to contact Talend support, I'm sure they'll help you fix this